# generate code for the multivalue attribute in Acceleo

Tags: acceleo

how I can generate code for the multivalue attribute?
In my metamodel, I have a class named A, and its attribute named B that is multivalue. 
Attribute B`s type is class C.
In the modelling, I set two value for attribute B. For example, C1 and C2.
Now, how to generate code for C1 and C2? (for example access to name of C1 and C2)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something along these lines:

```
[for (e : C | A.B)]
   This B attribute has a name of: [e.name/]
[/for]
```